# bind a click event only once for dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

Updated: **[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/XCfAQ/6/)**

The code will dynamically create a text link via a select box. How would you bind a click event to it only once so that every dynamically created link will only add data to the table once. I have tried `.one` and one of the approaches from [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) but it isn't working.

Code:

```
 $(function (){
  $('.area').each(function(){
   var area = $(this),
       selectbox = area.find('select'),
       show = area.find('.show'),   
       dialog_open =  $(this).find(".dialog_open");


    selectbox.change(function(){
      selectbox = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
      show.html('<a href="#" onclick="javascript: return false" class="dialog_open">'+selectbox+'</a>')
    });

    var foo = function() {
    var dialog_open_text = $(this).find(".dialog_open").text();
      $('td').html(dialog_open_text);
    };

    show.on( "click",dialog_open, foo );

    show.off( "click", dialog_open, foo );

  });

});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="area">
    <select>
        <option>Choose</option>
        <option>One</option>
        <option>Two</option>
    </select>
    <div class="show">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="area">
    <select>
        <option>Choose</option>
        <option>One</option>
        <option>Two</option>
    </select>
    <div class="show">
    </div>
</div>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title 1</th>
            <th>Title 2</th>
            <th>Title 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
show.on( "click",dialog_open, foo );

show.off( "click", dialog_open, foo );
```

to

```
show.one( "click",dialog_open, foo );
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XCfAQ/18/)

jQuerys [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) will attach an event handler which will detach itself after being invoked once.

Comment: I guess I wasn't beling explicit enough. This won't work when other dynamically created element replaces the old one.

Comment: @user35295, what do you want to happen when the dynamic element which replaced the old one is clicked? should it still change the text?

Comment: Yes. I want the new one also has the one click event function. They will also change the text once.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, in the fiddle that I provided, that is what happens. The element is created and the function is only run once, even if you change the link from 'one' to 'two'

Comment: Maybe my original example cannot get the point across because of the two same select boxes. Can you check this new [fiddle] once more(http://jsfiddle.net/XCfAQ/22/). You click on "1" and the text change, and then when you select "2" and click it,  does the text in the table change on your end? I want to apply the `one` click function to "1" and then resume the click function when I change it to "2"

Comment: No, it does not change on my end. Is that what you want? I am using chrome by the way

Comment: If you use on(not 'one') like in http://jsfiddle.net/XCfAQ/24/ it changes the text when changed from '1' to '2'

Comment: @user35295, which worked, 'on' or 'one so I can update the answer?